# restart specific website in IIS6 via command line

Tags: iis-6, restart

Does anyone know if I can restart a specific website within IIS 6 using the command line.

I don't want to use a blanket IISReset /restart command if I can avoid it.

I have a site that has an issue and is maxing out the server, I need to find a fix for it but in the meantime I also want to sleep so I'd like to just restart it every 10 minutes overnight to nurse it through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you actually want to recycle an Application pool rather than stop/start a website.

To do this you can use the IISAPP.vbs utility:

> cscript c:\windows\system32\iisapp.vbs /a "My AppPool" /r

You can run the utility with a /? flag for full usage details and some sample commandlines.

If you really want to start/stop a website you can use the ADSUTIL.vbs utility:

> cscript c:\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs STOP_SERVER W3SVC/1
>
> cscript c:\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs START_SERVER W3SVC/1

For more information on ADSUTIL.vbs please see this page :

[Using the Adsutil.vbs Administration Script (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d3df4bc9-0954-459a-b5e6-7a8bc462960c.mspx?mfr=true)